# pandas return auxilliary column from groupby and max

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a pandas DataFrame with 3 columns, A, B, and V.

I want a DataFrame with A as the index and one column, which contains the B for the maximum V

I can easily create a df with A and the maximum V using groupby, and then perform some machinations to extract the corresponding B, but that seems like the wrong idea.

I've been playing with combinations of groupby and agg with no joy.

Sample Data:

```
A,B,V
MHQ,Q,0.5192
MMO,Q,0.4461
MTR,Q,0.5385
MVM,Q,0.351
NCR,Q,0.0704
MHQ,E,0.5435
MMO,E,0.4533
MTR,E,-0.6716
MVM,E,0.3684
NCR,E,-0.0278
MHQ,U,0.2712
MMO,U,0.1923
MTR,U,0.3833
MVM,U,0.1355
NCR,U,0.1058
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
V = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'V': V})
res = df.groupby('A').apply(
    lambda x: x[x['V']==x['V'].max()]).set_index('A')['B'].to_frame()

res

    B
A    
1   3
2   6
3   9
4  12
```

Comment: That did the job.   I don't think I would have stumbled onto that on my own.   
Thank you.